# Python lambda method error with int, except my variable is an object not an int

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyside2

I am having trouble with an error which should not be possible..
Here is my situation :

I am developping a IHM in pyside2, so I am using widgets with signals like buttons.

I want to use a method inside an other method and all this is inside a for loop. So I am using the lambda method.
Except this time something strange happen. When I want to call a method of myObject inside the lambda, I have the error *int object has no attribute myMethod* but the method does exist and myObject is not an int !

This is a simple example of what I am doing :

```
myOtherObject = myOtherClass()
for i in range(10):
    myObject = myClass(i)
    myOtherObject.myOtherMethod.connect(lambda obj=myObject: obj.myMethod())
```

So I investigated this error and when I print the variable *obj* inside the lambda, it returns to me "0 or 2" everytime I am doing my signal, which is an On/Off button by the way.

- Button clicked On => *obj* = 2
- Button clicked Off => *obj* = 0

Any idea ?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: It's impossible to know based on this code alone. A first guess would be that `connect` expects a lambda that it will supply an argument for, thus ignoring your default value. We need to see how the lambda is called.

Comment: There's no MWE (or put plainly, we can't paste code and try it ourselves), not even the code where the method is called, so I can't say this for sure. But your lambdas will cause the exception you mentioned if you call it with 1 argument that is an `int`, not a `myClass`.

Comment: Try instead of a lambda using a normal named function, then you can debug/print it's parameters and return value

Comment: use `pathToggle.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, pathConf=pathConfig, check=pathToggleCheck: pathConf.checkToggle(check))`

Comment: @eyllanesc It's working !!! Thanks :)